# Pandas: Using variables to create dataframe with one row and column names from variable names

Tags: python, r, pandas, dataframe

Suppose I have some variables in Python. I am trying to create a 1-row Pandas dataframe, where the column names are the variables' names and the values in the row are from the variables.

For example, if I have this code:

```
pi  = 3.142
e   = 2.718
phi = 1.618
```

I would like a dataframe that conceptually looks like this:

```
     pi     e      phi
0   3.142   2.718  1.618
```

I tried the following, but everything is in one column, and the variable names are not added:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[pi, e, phi])
df
#        0
# 0  3.140
# 1  2.718
# 2  1.618
```

Note that I'm trying to replicate the behavior of some of my older R code.

```
pi  <- 3.142
e   <- 2.718
phi <- 1.618
df  <- data.frame(pi, e, phi)
df
#      pi     e   phi
# 1 3.142 2.718 1.618
```

Comment: Why it has an r tag though?

Comment: There's some R code in there at the end.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think you were looking for this format:

```
pd.DataFrame([[pi,e,phi]],columns=['pi','e','phi'])
```

Output:

```
      pi      e    phi
0  3.142  2.718  1.618
```

Comment: Is there any way to get the column names straight from the variable names without having to type them out again in the `columns` list?

Comment: Also, what does the syntax `[[pi,e,phi]]` with the double brackets indicate? That it's a list of one list? Why does the `columns` variable not have double brackets?

Comment: As for as define the column names from the variable names.  No not unless you put those variables into some sort of structure that includes their names.  the [[]] brackets makes it a list of list.  Hence a table if you think of it going down the across. to add a second 'row' it would look like [[],[]]

Comment: Just a list [] is seen as a series or a column in a pandas dataframe.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a list and dictionary like this

```
df = pd.DataFrame([{'pi':pi, 'e':e, 'phi':phi}])
```

which returns

```
df
Out[5]: 
       e    phi     pi
0  2.718  1.618  3.142
```

to preserve the column order, you can use the columns argument:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([{'pi':pi, 'e':e, 'phi':phi}], columns=['pi', 'e', 'phi'])
```

which returns

```
df
Out[9]: 
      pi      e    phi
0  3.142  2.718  1.618
```

Additional rows would go into separate dictionaries like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([{'pi':pi, 'e':e, 'phi':phi}, {'pi':2, 'e':3, 'phi':1}])
```

Comment: Thanks, but I would like to preserve the order of the columns as I provided.

Comment: Not a problem, you just have to explicitly list the column order.

Comment: In your answer, you have to type the variable names *three* times. :(

Comment: Yeah, that is true. Dictionaries are unordered, so to allow for reordering in the DataFrame, you have to provide the proper labels, and then provide the desired order in the columns argument.

Answer (score 2):

```
#Reference columns names only once and column order is retained.    
pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(data=[eval(k)],columns=[k]) for k in ['pi','e','phi']],axis=1)
Out[1226]: 
      pi      e    phi
0  3.142  2.718  1.618
```

Answer (score 0):

It is also convenient to use [`datar`](https://github.com/pwwang/datar), without having to pass the column names:

```py
>>> from datar.tibble import tibble
>>> 
>>> pi  = 3.142
>>> e   = 2.718
>>> phi = 1.618
>>> 
>>> df = tibble(pi, e, phi)
>>> df
         pi         e       phi
  <float64> <float64> <float64>
0     3.142     2.718     1.618
```

I am the author of the [`datar`](https://github.com/pwwang/datar) package. Feel free to submit issues if you have any questions.